# Bug in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS's sks package

Tags: 20.04, systemd

The sks package included in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has a small but critical bug. It insists on trying to write it's socket files to /var/run/sks. However, there is no such directory. First of all, /var/run got moved to /run, and second, as a tmpfs, /run would not necessarily have an sks directory unless it was made previously.

For now I've worked around that by creating an extra service for sks and sks-recon that simply checks if /var/run exists, if not it symlinks /run to /var/run, then looks to see if /var/run/sks exists, and if not, makes it and changes it's owner to the debian-sks user that sks runs as.

I would appreciate it if someone could actually forward such ideas to the package maintainers. It took me a LONG time to figure out that a non-existant directory is why sks kept complaining that it could not bind a socket and that another process probably already had.

For what it's worth, here's the quick script I threw together. Seems to work okay for me but could likely be improved.

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -d /var/run ] || ln -s /run /var/run
if [ ! -d /run/sks ]; then
  mkdir /run/sks
  chown debian-sks:debian-sks /run/sks
  chmod 770 /run/sks ;
fi
```

and here's the systemd service file to launch it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Directory Maker for SKS - Work around for bug in SKS code that insists on placing files in /var/run/sks
After=network.target
before=sks.service sks-recon.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
ExecStart=/var/lib/sks/sksdirmaker.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

An ugly work around perhaps, but it works. I tested it by first ensuring there was no /var/run symlink or /run/sks directory, then I ran:
systemctl start sks sks-dirmaker sks-recon

the result was that the directories were there and SKS loaded just fine.

Comment: Oh, I also edited the sks.service and sks-recon.services and added sks-dirmaker.service to their After= lines. The After line in sks.service now reads: 

After=local-fs.target network.target sks-dirmaker.service

and the line in sks-recon.service is:

sks.service sks-dirmaker.service

Granted the second was probably redundant, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Bugs (and suggested fixes which maintainers love) belong in a bug tracker.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  though you'll find details at https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/sks too (*Bug Reports* link which has a *Report a bug* link).  It's usually best to `ubuntu-bug sks` though, so it gains details from your system, rather than them potentially being requested later.